# Creating pandas database from multiple excel template files - python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, glob

My code below works but I'm new to python and it feels like there should be a much better way...

Companies fill in an Excel template with some stats about their workforce, so the files are in exactly the same format each time.

There are about 150 separate files and they are in Excel (.xls format, I'm not sure why but I wasn't involved in sending these out!). The required data are stored in individual cells:

Cell C6 = Company name,  Cell C13 = Number of jobs,  etc,  etc

What I want to do is create a row for each file, so my headings would be

filename | name | jobs | etc | etc

I've created an empty list and appended each new file value into the list, then created a dictionary and converted to a dataframe

```
all_files = []
all_name = []
all_jobs_current = []
#etc (approx 10 more)

for f in glob.glob('**/*.xls'):
    CF = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
    sheet = CF.sheet_by_name('Confirmation form')
    name = sheet.cell(5,2).value #cell C6
    jobs_current = sheet.cell(12,2).value #cell C13
    #etc

    all_files.append(f)
    all_name.append(name)
    all_jobs_current.append(jobs_current)
    #etc

d = {'Filename': all_files,
     'Name': all_name,
     'Jobs': all_jobs_current}
     #etc

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

EDIT 1: I've tried to update following the feedback (I accept I've probably written it incorrectly) but I'm getting the following error : **unhashable type: list**

```
dcell = {'Name': (5,2),
         'Jobs': (12,2)}
dlist = {k: [] for k in list(dcell.keys())}

for f in glob.glob('**/*.xls'):
    for k, v in dlist.items():
        CF = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
        sheet = CF.sheet_by_name('Confirmation form')
        dlist[v].append(sheet.cell(*dcell[k]).value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the work for a dictionary:

```
dcell = {'name': (5,2), 'jobs_current': (12,2) ... }
dlist = {k: [] for k in list(dcell.keys())}

for k, v in dlist.items():
    dlist[k].append(sheet.cell(*dcell[k]).value)
```

You would still need to iterate through file and create that filelist by itself, but then you can merge that list into `dlist`.

Comment: thanks for that, I can work out what your code is supposed to do but it's a bit more technical than anything I've done so far! I've tried to edit my original code but I'm getting the error *unhashable type: list*.

Comment: I've put my new code in the original post as EDIT 1

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it's `dlist[k]` instead of `dlist[v]`.